# What data structure to use for this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, graph, breadth-first-search

I have a `Matrix [N][M]`. I have filled this matrix with obstacles represented by `-1` and space for moving represented by `0`. I have also a person A represented by `-2`. This person have to check up, down, right and left to check if there is an obstacle. If there is not, then increment by `1`, place it in the current cell. When you finish with the checks go to the neighbors of that cell and do the same checks for its neighbors.

Obviously,the algorithm starts where person A is located and checks the above stuff that I wrote. My job is to find a particular cell where person A and person B could meet but the path must be the shortest possible. I guess that the algorithm should remember which cells have incremented.

- Should I use some kind of data structure for this task ?
- And, when does the algorithm has to stop ?

Comment: You can think about your matrix as a graph. And your algorithm is BFS (if I understand you correctly). Just check if you have already incremented the value for the neighbor cell. If not - mark this cell as incremented and put this neighbor to the queue.

Comment: What is the purpose of this algorithm? Would you like to find all cell that the person can reach? Or to reach some particular other cell?

Comment: to find a particular cell where person A and person B could meet but the path must be the shortest possible.

Comment: So there is person B? Which path must be the shortest? The path of the person A, of the person B or the sum of the paths of person B and person A combined?

Comment: Did you take a look at bfs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search? Why do  you think this approach will not work for you?

Comment: Let's say the meeting point of the people A and B should be somewhere in the middle I guess. It is the shortest path both for A and for B.

Comment: So you mean, that the time/number of simultaneous moves until both persons meet must be minimal (as they move simultaneously), don't you? And what about bfs?

Comment: "Somewhere in the middle I guess" is not very helpful. If you don't know the requirements, it's pretty unlikely that we can help you discover a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let reformulate your problem. You have a labyrinth where each cell of Matrix [N][M] represents -1 if this is a wall or 0 if this is a space. Also you have a locations of persons P1=(X1,Y1) and P2=(X2,Y2). You don't need to save person locations as -2 in your matrix, but you can. Task is to find all possible cells, where first person could meet second person with minimal summary path of them. This is absolutely the same as finding cells that creates  shortest path from P1 to P2. Second person can stay in their starting cell, and move only first person.

So, you have a matrix with walls, start point and end point, you should return shortest path from start to end point. This is the classical task for breadth-first search algorithm. Also this can be solved with A* with Manhattan distance heuristic

UPD.

ead comment is correct that is not the same as finding shortest path, but it is easy to change a little bit bfs so that we can find all cells that can belong to some of shortest paths. We should track not only one predecessor of some cell in bfs:

- For every cell we should store minimal distance value for this cell from starting point.
- 4 bits, that represents if this cell reachable from one of 4 directions with this distance. Usually we store coordinated (or direction) that tells from what cell we came.

For example we have matrix and points P1 and P2, so we have 2 shortest paths here:

```
P1 -- 0 -- 0
|     |    |
|     |    |
0  -- 0 -- P2
```

We track set (can implement as setted bits) of direction from what we can reach this cell, let them called UDLR:

```
P1 -- L(1) -- L(2)     in brackets written shortest distance
|      |      |
|      |      |
U(1)-- LU(2)--LU(3)
```

Then we need second bfs that started from P2 to P1 and catch all cells that can belongs to one of shortest paths.

Comment: valdem wrote: "Task is to find all possible cells, where first person could meet second person with minimal summary path of them." - I'm not sure this is the right task/problem and this is definitely not the same as  "returning the shortest path from start to end" as there could be more than one shortest path.

Comment: a very nice idea to use A* instead of bfs and to give a direction to the search! It will be probable faster for bigger problems in average...

Comment: I'm still not convinced, that yours interpretation of the task is right, but your interpretation of the problem is interesting enough! Yet I don't understand the necessity of UDLR bits. And in your example there are three shortest paths: d(own)r(ight)r, rdr, and rrd.